# Non-blocking check for signals in a loop

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, signals

I have a thread in an application that has a loop like this:

```
...
while (1)
{
    checkDatabase();
    checkChildren();

    sleep(3);
}
...
```

`checkDatabase()` is self-explanatory; `checkChildren()` simply calls `waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)` to deal with child processes that have either exited or received a signal.

The application works fairly well, but it has default signal handling. The problem is that this parent process has a number of threads (don't worry about child processes for now) and I don't have any experience with synchronous signals, let alone in a POSIX threads application. I have used `signal()` before but apparently it's non-portable and it doesn't do what I need anyway. I have no experience at all with `sigaction` methods, and I can't find good documentation on how to fill in the structs and so on.

What I need to do is to synchronously catch terminating signals like `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM` and `SIGQUIT` in the above loop (and I need to ignore `SIGPIPE` altogether so that I can catch the `EPIPE` error from IO methods), so it would look like this:

```
...
while (1)
{
    checkDatabase();
    checkChildren();
    checkForSignals();

    sleep(3);
}
...
```

All other threads should not have anything to do with the signal; only the thread that executes this loop should be aware of it. And, obviously, it needs to be a *non-blocking* check so the loop doesn't block during its first iteration. The method called if a signal is found will sort out the other threads and destroy mutexes, and all that.

Could anyone please give me a heads-up? Many thanks.

Comment: By `synchronous signals`, do you mean you'd prefer to avoid registering signal handlers?

Comment: Yes, I thought it would be better organised and also safer, as I understand that some calls are unsafe in an asynchronous signal handler. I guessed that this was the best way to do it, but I'm not 100% sure. One of the concerns was also associated with ANSI signal handling not being portable, although it's not a major issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Following the question's comments, and for completeness, this solution tries to avoid signal handlers.)*

It is possible to block signals from being raised through [sigprocmask()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigprocmask) (or, rather, [pthread_sigmask()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_sigmask) since you're using threads). From there on, the signals that were raised but blocked are available through [sigpending()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigpending).

Therefore, you could do something like (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
sigset_t blocked;
sigemptyset(&blocked);
sigaddset(&blocked, SIGINT);
sigaddset(&blocked, SIGTERM);
sigaddset(&blocked, SIGQUIT);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &blocked, NULL); // Block SIGINT, SIGTERM and SIGQUIT.
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);                   // Ignore SIGPIPE.
```

Then, later:

```
void checkForSignals(void)
{
    sigset_t pending;
    sigpending(&pending);
    if (sigismember(&pending, SIGINT)) {
        // Handle SIGINT...
    }
    if (sigismember(&pending, SIGTERM)) {
        // Handle SIGTERM...
    }
    if (sigismember(&pending, SIGQUIT)) {
        // Handle SIGQUIT...
    }
}
```

Since `sigpending()` does not block, this seems to match your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Presumably, child processes created after the first snippet will inherit the signal mask and stuff, so would I need to call `signal(sig, SIG_DFL)` to undo the sigmask stuff?

Comment: The signal mask will indeed be inherited, you'll have to call `pthread_sigmask()` with `SIG_SETMASK` and an empty `sigset_t` (by calling `sigemptyset()` but not `sigaddset()`) in the child process to restore the default behavior.

Comment: Okay thanks. One more thing, when should the first snippet be called? Before or after creating the threads?

Comment: It's easier to call it once, on the main thread, then create the other threads afterwards so they inherit the setup. Otherwise, you would have to call it for each thread.

Answer (score 2):

Create a signal handler for `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM` and `SIGQUIT`, using the same function. In that signal function just set a flag that can be polled in your loop.

Something like this:

```
/* Global variable, will be set to non-zero if SIGINT, SIGTERM or SIGQUIT is caught */
int term_signal_set = 0;

void my_signal_handler(int)
{
    term_signal_set = 1;
}

/* ... */

signal(SIGINT, my_signal_handler);
signal(SIGTERM, my_signal_handler);
signal(SIGQUIT, my_signal_handler);
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);  /* So functions return EPIPE */

while (1)
{
    /* ... */

    if (term_signal_set > 0)
        break;  /* Or do something else */

    sleep(3);
}
```

Comment: It seems surprisingly simple but looks like it would work despite being asynchronous. How can I make sure that child processes (as opposed to the threads of the parent) don't mimic this? I use `signal(signal, SIG_DFL)` at the start of the children, right? Also, note my comment on my question above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In a multithreaded application receiving a signal, there is no predetermination, which thread receives the signal. Typical workaraounds include setting a global variable in the signal handler and checking it from a dedicated thread.

So in your case the signal handler (called from whatever thread) would just set something like a global variable for the signal received, and in `CheckForSignals()` you would test it.

Answer (score 0):

`sigaction` is the way to go. `man sigaction` should help you. Here is an example from the web

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

struct sigaction act;

void sighandler(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *ptr)
{
    printf("Received signal %d\n", signum);
    printf("Signal originates from process %lu\n",
        (unsigned long)info->si_pid);
}

int main()
{
    printf("I am %lu\n", (unsigned long)getpid());
        memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));

    act.sa_sigaction = sighandler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

    sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, NULL);
        // Waiting for CTRL+C...
    sleep(100);  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not use printf (and other non-reentrant functions, such as malloc) in a signal handler. In this demonstration program it looks harmless, but **don't try this at work**